# unable to write a value into excel sheet using selenium webdriver with Apache POI

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

As per the requirement, a web form needs to be filled by taking values from a excel sheet. After filling in all the values, a numeric value gets auto populated in one of the fields in the same web form.

It is  numeric value from just one web  field  that needs to be written in to the same excel sheet that was used to read values, code is as below:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(".xlsx")); 
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFSheet sheet3 = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();

String NAME = sheet2.getRow(2).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
driver.findElement(By.id("@@")).sendKeys(NAME);
```

like wise many cells are filled.

after that to get value from webpage into excel sheet:

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.id("!!")).getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(value);
```

The value is correctly getting printed.

using the below code the value is not getting displayed

```
CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
XSSFSheet sheet4 = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");
Row row1 = sheet4.createRow((short)0);
// Create a cell and put a value in it.
Cell cell = row1.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(value);
```

Comment: what happens if you hard code the way. `cell.setCellValue(10);`,  does it throws any exception?

Comment: try setting `cell type` before setting value as `cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);`

Comment: @Gaurang Shah...I have tried hardcoding the value, still the same happens. no error and the value is not getting written in the page.

Comment: @Kushal,  This  throws a compile  time error: "String can not be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: please make sure your imports are : `import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;`